# Find Root Solution

Tags: soft-question, logarithms, roots, recreational-mathematics

$$\frac{3 (1 - 2x)}{{\sqrt[4]{(1 - x)x}}} = \log_2\left(\frac{1 - x}{x}\right) \sqrt {2} $$
It is clear the $\frac{1}{2}$ is a solution, but there are others solutions. If we subtract this two side of equation and plot [in a visualization software](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsFFX.png), we can see that are others roots. I like to find the solution that are close to $x = 0.2$.

[image]

**Addendum:** I need a exact solution.

Comment: Start with $x=\sin^2t$

Comment: This is equivalent to $2^{f(x)}=g(x)$. If the any simplification and restriction doesn't work, probably the elementary solution doesn't exist.

Comment: Solve the equation numerically.

Comment: I want an exact solution, I forgot to say that. This root is only useful for me if it is exact, it is part of a proof.

Comment: Try Mathematica or Maple. If they don't give an exact solution then the elementary solution doesnt exist. (most likely)

Comment: I don't think it has other exact solutions.Mathematica command findroot(3(1-2*x)/(sqrt(2)*((1-x)*x)^0.25)==log((1-x)/x)/log(2),{x,0.1}) gives one numerical solution x=0.175235 near 0.1.

Comment: @SknotsHtam If having an exact expression is relevant to a proof, it would help if you would tell us about the proof in question. See [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). In particular, the *include the source and motivation for your question* section.

Comment: @k.defaoite this is not an interesting theoretical problem, it’s just an artificial problem that doesn’t go beyond that

Answer (score 1):

As you did, consider that you look for the zero's of function $$f(x)=\frac{3 (1 - 2x)}{{\sqrt {2}} {\sqrt[4]{(1 - x)x}}} - \log_2\left(\frac{1 - x}{x}\right)$$
Beside the trivial $x=0.5$, graphing, you noticed three other roots close to $x=0.2$, $x=0.8$ and another close to $x=1$; if you plot again the function between $0.95$ and $1.0$, the largest root is close to $x=0.99$.

Now, using these values a starting points, use Newton method and get the following iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 0.2000000000 \\
 1 & 0.1704681790 \\
 2 & 0.1750941042 \\
 3 & 0.1752348886 \\
 4 & 0.1752350156
\end{array}
\right)$$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 0.8000000000 \\
 1 & 0.8295318210 \\
 2 & 0.8249058958 \\
 3 & 0.8247651114 \\
 4 & 0.8247649844
\end{array}
\right)$$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 0.9900000000 \\
 1 & 0.9912580691 \\
 2 & 0.9911109005 \\
 3 & 0.9911082777 \\
 4 & 0.9911082769
\end{array}
\right)$$